# Angular2 - accessing DOM element attributes of one component from another component

Tags: angular

What is in your opinion the current best way of accessing DOM attributes from a different component in angular2?

Let's say I have a component B and C which are tabs of component A.

In the component B, I have an input element, into which I just typed the value. 
How do I access this text value attribute in component B, from inside the component C?

I want to know the easiest as well as the most recommended method and somehow summarize how this can be done, all in one place.

As Angular2 has evolved, I feel there is a lot of confusion surrounding this topic.

Thanks

Comment: Excellent documentation in the official docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html